# Android - Encoding MP3 from Stereo to Mono channel

Tags: android, audio, mp3, android-mediacodec

My app must encode user selected mp3 to mono channel and save this mp3. Can I use default android methods for encode?
I try to understand `MediaCodec` but it's too hard to understand media configs. Maybe there is a simple method for this? Or reay-to-use code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're really asking, but I remember I had a project where I needed to convert files to mono with given parameters. For me, the "sox" tool did the job just fine, but it was under Linux. Given that Android is supposedly Linux, maybe this could help you too.
This is the command I used:

sox myfile -r 16000 -c 1 -b 16 outputfile

If I remember correctly, the commands are:
-r for the rate
-c for channel
-b for bits

I found a blog doing some explanations on it here: https://www.nesono.com/node/275
You could search online for more info if you think you could use this in your project, as I'm not an expert by all means with it.

Comment: i found sox lib here for adroid https://github.com/corballis/sox-wrapper-java but there is no mp3 support

Comment: What about adding the plugin sox-plugins-freeworld too? I know that for linux adds mp3 support

Comment: I took a look at http://sox.sourceforge.net/soxformat.html and they are saying that, in order to get mp3 support, you have to build sox from source with mp3 libraries 'MAD & LAME), or obtain pre-built dynamically loadable libraries

Comment: Where I can find step-by-step solution to add library to my android app?

Comment: you can check their instruction from their  git https://sourceforge.net/p/sox/code/ci/master/tree/ or, alternatively, you can take a look at the ffmpeg tool and see if it can be integrated with your application.

Comment: I think I need something more simple to integrate